# Find the sum-of-products expansions

Tags: functions

Find the sum-of-products expansions of the Boolean function $F(x, y, z)$ that equals $1$ if and only if

a) $x = 0.$

b) $xy = 0.$

c) $x + y = 0.$

d) $xyz = 0$.

Comment: What have you already Tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll get you started. I'll use an overline to denote "not": e.g., $\overline a =$ ~a.

$(1) \quad f(x, y, z) = \overline x $

$(2) \quad f(x, y, z) = \overline{xy} = \overline x + \overline y$.

For $(c)$, what is $\overline{x + y}$ equivalent to? Hint, use DeMorgan's

For $(d)$, what is $\overline{xyz}$ equivalent to? Again, use Demorgan's, as in $(2)$